# Swift Network call with php Api endPoint

Tags: php, ios, swift

Can someone help me with the following issue?

I am not able to retrieve the value for **id**.

the "**id**" is alway empty when I do post from a iOS network call.

**Swift 3 for Network call :**

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "URL HERE")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "id=2"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

**api.php** 
**PHP code to retrieve the value from server side.**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(isset($_POST["id"]) == 0) {

        $id = isset($_POST["id"]);

    }
}
```

Comment: first try to print what you get in the print_r($_POST) . do you get it?

Comment: Array
(
    ["id"] => "2"
) 

I am  not able reterive the value:

$id = $_POST['id'];
  
  echo "Value is: ".$id;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the PHP code. On line 3, if `isset` is `FALSE`, set `$id` value to the id-parameter. You want it to be if `isset` is `TRUE`.

Change the 0 to a 1. It's just a small typo.

It also looks like you might have gotten `isset` a bit wrong. `isset` returns a bool, whether a variable has a value or not. So `$id = isset($_POST["id"]);` tells you if an ID is given, not the value. If you want the value drop `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the value with the following code.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(isset($_POST["id"]) == 0) {
        $arr = array_values($_POST);
        //print_r($arr);
        echo "Value is: ".$arr['0'];
    }
}
```